# When is posting my own answer to my question rejected by answer ban?

Tags: support, self-answer

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [How to fix corrupted boot partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890686/how-to-fix-corrupted-boot-partition)

I cannot post an answer to my own question.  I was attempting to do so in order to clean up after myself and demonstrate good answer behavior.  I thought that this would be a good way to work toward getting my answer ban lifted.  Is this not allowed under an answer ban?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have an answer ban, **you cannot post any answers.  At all.  Not even to your own questions.**  All answers are blocked when you have an answer-posting ban.

This is part of the system.  You can't post any answers on a site where you have an answer ban until you resolve the issue which got you answer-banned to begin with, and show other positive contributions until the system removes the answer ban.  (Moderators and SE Employees can't remove such bans)

[You might want to visit the Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/answer-bans) for more details, but you need to provide other non-answer contributions to the site so the system can see that other positive contributions outweigh the negative contributions that got you the answer-ban to begin with.

Also read [this thread on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) which is also very relevant and touches upon the details about what led to the ban and what you can do to fix the problem.

---

Note though that I did poke your account, and take a look to *guess* as to why you have an answer ban.  What I found was: all 4 of the answers you have made since registering have been deleted for one reason or another.

Of those 4, all of them received a number of "Not an Answer" or moderator-attention-needed flags and the answers were deleted as a result of the flags being deemed 'helpful'.  And they received those flags rightfully so - none of your posted answers are *actually* answers, and are more along the lines of comments.

When a vast majority of your answers are either deleted by yourself or deleted and have a number of negative flags, it tends to be one of the reasons you get an answer ban.

As stated above, you need to show positive contribution outside that of answering to the point the system can remove the ban.  This is, however, not measurable by moderators or SE employees in any meaningful way, so we can't say *when* (or even *if*) the system will remove the answering ban.  (However, a vast majority of your answers are all "not an answer" and therefore would have been deleted anyways, which probably led to the answer ban.)